# pam faillock preauth -- what does it do?

Tags: pam

I have a file `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` that says this (in part).  I have added line numbers that aren't in the original file.

```
1 auth required pam_env.so
2 auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=900
3 auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_unix.so
4 auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 unlock_time=900
5 auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 unlock_time=900
6 auth required pam_deny.so
```

I don't understand what line 2 is doing.  The rest of the lines I understand:

1. Set my environment variables
2. ???
3. Check the user's password.  If the password is good then jump to line 5.
4. The password was bad.  Log that fact in the faillock table.  Stop processing the password.  Reject the login attempt.  If we have 5 bad login attempts, then lock the account for 15 minutes.
5. The password was good. Clear the faillock table for this user.  Allow him to log in and proceed.  Stop processing.
6. We probably should never get to this line, but if we do, then reject the login attempt.

What is the purpose of line 2?  None of my testing has shown any specific reason to have it or not have it.  The man page says:

> The module just examines whether the user should be blocked from
>   accessing the service in case there were anomalous number of failed
>   consecutive authentication attempts recently.

I thought that this means

> Check to see if the account is locked.  If the account is locked, then
>   it doesn't matter what password is entered, we will reject the login
>   attempt.

...but that isn't the case.  As far as I can tell, the `authfail` line is actually locking the account, and the account cannot be logged into with or without the `preauth` line.

So what (if anything) is it actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_faillock) the `preauth` line

> is optional if *authsucc* is used.

If you look at the examples in the man page, preauth can be used to display information that an account is locked (without silent) or if you change it to requisite it prevents the password query for a locked account.